# Data snooped predictors trained out of sample, fit on the original data

Tags: dataset, inference

Suppose I have a model, Y ~ X1, X2, ...

The predictors (X1,X2..) are snooped on sample data S1.  That is they are chosen, because the seem related to Y in sample.

The model, Y ~ X1, X2, ... is then trained on a completely new data set, S2.  So parameters, p1, p2... are estimated.

My question is, suppose you used the parameters (trained out of sample) and the predictors of the S1 (original) data set to predict the Y's in the original snooped data.  Are the predictions, Yhat, biased?

So the model is estimated out of sample and then you go back to the original sample to predict the Y characteristic of interest.  Are the new predictions biased by the original snooping?  Or is the original snooping washed away because the model was trained on a new sample and those parameter estimates are unbiased?